# JSON file specific line editing

Tags: python, json, line

I'd like to ask what is the best way to replace specific line in multiple json files. In everyfile its the same line that needs to be replaced. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ipQ.png)

```
import json
with open('3.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data['attributes']:
    item['value'] = item['value'].replace("Untitled", item['BgTest'])

with open('3.json', 'w') as d:
    json.dump(data, d)
```

I tried this code I found but it keeps giving me an error:

```
"/Users/jakubpitonak/Desktop/NFT/Gnomes Collection/ART-GEN-TUTORIAL 2.0/bin/python" /Users/jakubpitonak/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/update.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jakubpitonak/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/update.py", line 25, in <module>
    item['value'] = item['value'].replace("Untitled", item['BgTest'])
KeyError: 'BgTest'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `item['BgTest']` does not exist in the items you're iterating through. I think you want to replace the `"Untitled"` value with the value `"BgTest"`. In that case, replace the for loop with the one below:

```py
for item in data['attributes']:
    if item['value'] == 'Untitled':
        item['value'] = 'BgTest'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open('3.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data['attributes']:
    item['value'] = "Your value here"

with open('3.json', 'w') as d:
    json.dump(data, d)
```

`BgTest` is not a valid key for the example you posted. If you only have that key in certain rows of the list you can not use it in the for loop.